# Errors when running buildozer in Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: python, python-3.x, kivy, ubuntu-18.04

I am getting various errors when running buildozer on Ubuntu 18.04. I am trying to create an App with Kivy, however, when I run this buildozer init command, it runs and downloads all dependencies modules and at the end, it gives me this error.  Can someone please help me on how to move forward from here to resolve this error. Thank you.

```
[INFO]:    -> running ndk-build V=1
[INFO]:    <- directory context /home/bhavin/apptest/.buildozer/android/platform/python-for-android
[INFO]:    Building setuptools for armeabi-v7a
[INFO]:    setuptools apparently isn't already in site-packages
[INFO]:    Installing setuptools into site-packages
[INFO]:    -> directory context 
/home/bhavin/apptest/.buildozer/android/platform/build/build/other_builds/setuptools- 
python3/armeabi-v7a__ndk_target_21/setuptools
[INFO]:    -> running python setup.py install -O2 --...(and 107 more)
Exception in thread background thread for pid 24611:
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/usr/lib/python3.6/threading.py", line 916, in _bootstrap_inner
self.run()
File "/usr/lib/python3.6/threading.py", line 864, in run
self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
File "/home/bhavin/buildozer-env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sh.py", line 1540, in wrap
fn(*args, **kwargs)
File "/home/bhavin/buildozer-env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sh.py", line 2459, in background_thread
handle_exit_code(exit_code)
File "/home/bhavin/buildozer-env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sh.py", line 2157, in fn
return self.command.handle_command_exit_code(exit_code)
File "/home/bhavin/buildozer-env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sh.py", line 815, in 
handle_command_exit_code
raise exc
sh.ErrorReturnCode_1:

RAN: /home/bhavin/apptest/.buildozer/android/platform/build/build/other_builds/
hostpython3/desktop/hostpython3/native-build/python setup.py install -O2 -- 
root=/home/bhavin/apptest/.buildozer/android/platform/build/build/python-installs/bhavinapp -- 
install-lib=.

STDOUT:
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "setup.py", line 11, in <module>
import setuptools
File "/home/bhavin/apptest/.buildozer/android/platform/build/build/other_builds/setuptools- 
python3/armeabi-v7a__ndk_target_21/setuptools/setuptools/__init__.py", line 20, in <module>
from setuptools.dist import Distribution, Feature
File "/home/bhavin/apptest/.buildozer/android/platform/build/build/other_builds/setuptools- 
python3/armeabi-v7a__ndk_target_21/setuptools/setuptools/dist.py", line 36, in <module>
from setuptools import windows_support
File "/home/bhavin/apptest/.buildozer/android/platform/build/build/other_builds/setuptools- 
python3/armeabi-v7a__ndk_target_21/setuptools/setuptools/windows_support.py", line 2, in <module>
import ctypes
File "/home/bhavin/apptest/.buildozer/android/platform/build/build/other_builds/
/hostpython3/desktop/hostpython3/Lib/ctypes/__init__.py", line 7, in <module>
from _ctypes import Union, Structure, Array
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '_ctypes'

STDERR:

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/usr/lib/python3.6/runpy.py", line 193, in _run_module_as_main
"__main__", mod_spec)
File "/usr/lib/python3.6/runpy.py", line 85, in _run_code
exec(code, run_globals)
File "/home/bhavin/apptest/.buildozer/android/platform/python-for- 
android/pythonforandroid/toolchain.py", line 1192, in <module>
main()
File "/home/bhavin/apptest/.buildozer/android/platform/python-for- 
android/pythonforandroid/entrypoints.py", line 18, in main
ToolchainCL()
File "/home/bhavin/apptest/.buildozer/android/platform/python-for- 
android/pythonforandroid/toolchain.py", line 668, in __init__
getattr(self, args.subparser_name.replace('-', '_'))(args)
File "/home/bhavin/apptest/.buildozer/android/platform/python-for- 
android/pythonforandroid/toolchain.py", line 153, in wrapper_func
build_dist_from_args(ctx, dist, args)
File "/home/bhavin/apptest/.buildozer/android/platform/python-for- 
android/pythonforandroid/toolchain.py", line 206, in build_dist_from_args
args, "ignore_setup_py", False
File "/home/bhavin/apptest/.buildozer/android/platform/python-for- 
android/pythonforandroid/build.py", line 577, in build_recipes
recipe.build_arch(arch)
File "/home/bhavin/apptest/.buildozer/android/platform/python-for- 
android/pythonforandroid/recipe.py", line 844, in build_arch
self.install_python_package(arch)
File "/home/bhavin/apptest/.buildozer/android/platform/python-for- 
android/pythonforandroid/recipe.py", line 863, in install_python_package
_env=hpenv, *self.setup_extra_args)
File "/home/bhavin/apptest/.buildozer/android/platform/python-for- 
android/pythonforandroid/logger.py", line 180, in shprint
for line in output:
File "/home/bhavin/buildozer-env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sh.py", line 863, in next
self.wait()
File "/home/bhavin/buildozer-env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sh.py", line 792, in wait
self.handle_command_exit_code(exit_code)
File "/home/bhavin/buildozer-env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sh.py", line 815, in 
handle_command_exit_code
raise exc
sh.ErrorReturnCode_1:

RAN: /home/bhavin/apptest/.buildozer/android/platform/build/build/other_builds/
hostpython3/desktop/hostpython3/native-build/python setup.py install -O2 -- 
root=/home/bhavin/apptest/.buildozer/android/platform/build/build/python-installs/bhavinapp -- 
install-lib=.

STDOUT:

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "setup.py", line 11, in <module>
import setuptools
File "/home/bhavin/apptest/.buildozer/android/platform/build/build/other_builds/setuptools- 
python3/armeabi-v7a__ndk_target_21/setuptools/setuptools/__init__.py", line 20, in <module>
from setuptools.dist import Distribution, Feature
File "/home/bhavin/apptest/.buildozer/android/platform/build/build/other_builds/setuptools- 
python3/armeabi-v7a__ndk_target_21/setuptools/setuptools/dist.py", line 36, in <module>
from setuptools import windows_support
File "/home/bhavin/apptest/.buildozer/android/platform/build/build/other_builds/setuptools- 
python3/armeabi-v7a__ndk_target_21/setuptools/setuptools/windows_support.py", line 2, in <module>
import ctypes
File "/home/bhavin/apptest/.buildozer/android/platform/build/build/other_builds/hostpython3/
desktop/hostpython3/Lib/ctypes/__init__.py", line 7, in <module>
from _ctypes import Union, Structure, Array
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '_ctypes'

STDERR:

# Command failed: /home/bhavin/buildozer-env/bin/python3 -m pythonforandroid.toolchain create -- 
dist_name=bhavinapp --bootstrap=sdl2 --requirements=python3,kivy --arch armeabi-v7a --copy-libs -- 
color=always --storage-dir="/home/bhavin/apptest/.buildozer/android/platform/build" --ndk-api=21
#
# Buildozer failed to execute the last command
# The error might be hidden in the log above this error
# Please read the full log, and search for it before
# raising an issue with buildozer itself.
# In case of a bug report, please add a full log with log_level = 2
(buildozer-env) bhavin@bhavin-VirtualBox:~/apptest$
```

Answer (score 0):

Install the libffi headers (might be a package with a name like `libffi-dev`), then delete the .buildozer file in your app dir, then run buildozer again.

Comment: so I run this sudo apt-get install -y libffi-dev first. Delete buildozer file means uninstalling it or? Sorry, I am very new to using Ubuntu.

Comment: Just delete the folder named ".buildozer", which you'll find in the directory where you ran buildozer. It is a hidden file, so you might not see it by default in your file manager.

Comment: I have the following files: bhavin@bhavin-VirtualBox:~$ ls
apptest        Desktop    Downloads         Music     Public     Videos
buildozer-env  Documents  examples.desktop  Pictures  Templates

Comment: Running buildozer again means I run this pip install buildozer?

Comment: No, run the buildozer program, `buildozer android debug`

Comment: I installed libffi-dev and deleted the .buildozer file. When I run buildozer -v android debug, it says buildozer: command not found.

Comment: Did you uninstall buildozer or something? Neither of those things will have affected whether buildozer is installed.

Comment: Can you please send me the whole procedure on how to install buildozer. I am installing a new virtual box with Ubuntu 80.04 again and start from fresh.

Comment: I mean Ubuntu 18.04

Comment: How would I upload the error file as I have copied all errors in the notepad file and you can then review the same.